# How do I add an echo inside an array?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to show products from a certain category on a page like his:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'product_cat' => 'prcategory1', 'orderby' => 'price');
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
```

This one works. However, I'd like 'prcategory1' to be taken from a custom field of the page. Something like this (incorrect code incoming):

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'product_cat' => 'get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'custom_cat_name', TRUE); ?>', 'orderby' => 'price');
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
```

Comment: You want to print the return of `get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'custom_cat_name', TRUE)` inside `$args` array ?

Comment: Yes. Tried it in several ways, but didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

There is some errors in your code, try this for your array :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'product_cat' => get_post_meta(
        get_the_ID(),
        'custom_cat_name',
        TRUE
    ),
    'orderby' => 'price'
)
```